# What edition should I use for standalone deployments?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

If I want to create a project that is fairly basic (VS2010, C# & a SQL database) and it is to be deployed to other people's PCs to be used as a stand-alone program, where they do not have SQL of any kind installed (until my deployment installs it), should I just use SQL Server Express to create the Database ?

I have used SQL Server Data Centre edition on a work laptop to create a small personal program, but I get the impression that the PCs I use it on will also need a full production version of SQL Server installed, and not just Express, is that correct ?!?

Comment: DataCenter edition on your laptop? That's kind of like hooking a nitro kit up to a Segway.

Comment: @Aaron - it's not my laptop, it's a work one, I'm just a programmer, this could have been anybody's a few weeks ago !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out SQL Server compact.  I think it is the best solution for your particular situation:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876

Comment: This is the route I would go down too. I found this link useful for some example code: http://arcanecode.com/2007/04/13/sql-server-compact-edition-with-c-and-vbnet/

Comment: I've just looked, this is free (obviously if I am putting it my own PC, not the work one, this is important !!!), what do I lose in functionality ? Presumably nothing relevant for a small project like this !!!

Comment: It's perfect for this project...don't even have to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Your customers can install SQL Server Express, or you can do it for them. SQL Server Express *is* a "full production version" of SQL Server, just not for heavy usage.

Comment: "Full" is in the license of the beholder.  Have a look at what Microsoft thinks of the various editions [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx).

Comment: Bottom line is that I am writing a program for a friend, not a customer. I understand that when I save the Project and install it on his machine, it will install a free version of SQL Server on his PC, presumably Express, I am a complete Novice at this. Are you saying that the fact that I created the Database in SQL Server Data Centre edition should be irrelevant ?!?

Comment: Express does not include full-text search, SQL Server Agent, indexed views, ... .  Please check the link in my first comment to see what the differences are and determine if they impact your "fairly basic" situation.